# Cross-compiling for a specific platform -- linking libc

Tags: gcc, linker, cross-compiling

I have to compile a simple binary for a very old Linux system.  I have no gcc/build libs available on the target machine but I do have access to the machine.

I am having trouble compiling the code on my machine and having it execute on target machine.

I am copying libc.so to my local machine and trying to compile and link the program so that it will execute on the target machine.

I have copied the libc from the target machine to mine and tried compiling it with my target executable.

this has gotten closes to a successful execution:

`gcc -nostdlib ./libc-[version].so myFile.c -emain -o outfile.out`

upon execution a very simple PoC test program runs, and then seg faults upon exit.  the actual program simply seg faults.

It seems I have somewhat of a lack of understanding of linking.  Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It seems I have somewhat of a lack of understanding of linking.

You do. A "normal" user-level program doesn't start executing at `main`, it starts at `_start`.

The `_start` symbol typically comes from `crt0.o` file (part of libc), and knows how to "interface" between the way the kernel supplies arguments, and the way `main` expects to find them. It also initializes various data that must be initialized before `main` runs (e.g. `stdio` streams).

What you want to do then is:

1. Find out the actual link command that `gcc main.o` performs. You can do so by adding the `-v` flag.
2. Replicate such command, providing `crt0.o` and other input files, *appropriate* for your version of target libc.

It might be easier to spin up a VM with the OS matching your target (and with old tools that target it), and build your program inside of that VM.

Otherwise you'll likely have to set up a full cross-compiler environment (which includes libc and all other libraries you need). This is *not* a trivial proposition, and is certainly not accomplished by copying `libc.so` from the target machine. But it *is* [well-documented](https://www6.software.ibm.com/developerworks/education/l-cross/l-cross-ltr.pdf) and is certainly doable (with some skill).